# How to sync cordova builded app with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

How does firebase sync a Cordova built app ???

I do want my firebase console to identify my Cordova apk.

(knowing how many users are on my app, analytics... )

Answer (score -1):

---

You can use cordova-plugin-firebase https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: This plugin fails on build after may 5 update of google